# Desabilitar Função .click em DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou fazendo um jogo e preciso de uma rotina que desabilite o clique pelo menos até terminar a função.

A função é esta abaixo. Quando eu clicar no elemento e executar essa função com `touchstart` e `click` quero que dentro da `div` onde está esse elemento não permita a função do `click` até que termine essa função.

Como posso fazer ?

```
$('#boxes > .box').on("touchstart", function(){
        var cor = $(this.data('cor');
        media.play("cor-"+cor);
    }).mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout(time);
        var cor = $(this).data('cor');
        if(!$(this).is('.bigsize')){
            time = setTimeout(function(){
                media.play("cor-"+cor);
            }, 200);
        }
    }).on("touchstart click", function(e){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("move")){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("div#escolha-e-clique").addClass("out");
            var elm = $(this);
            elm.addClass("move");
            $("div#boxes > .box, div#boxes > .box-lock").not($(this)).addClass('toenter');
            setTimeout(function(){
                media.play("scroll-01-ascend");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    elm.addClass('bigsize');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            media.play("chime-01");
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $("div#gift").addClass('anime');
                                var randomGift = Math.floor((Math.random() * totalGifts) + 1);
                                var gift = $('div#gift > .gifts > div:nth-child('+randomGift+')');
                                gift.addClass('active');
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    gift.addClass('rotate');
                                    //Frase do objeto
                                    var audio = gift.data('audio');
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        media.play(audio);
                                    }, 1400);
                                }, 2000);

                                media.play("tada");
                            }, 500);
                        }, 250);
                    }, 500);
                }, 500);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

---

Consegui desabilitar um elemento que eu precisava.
Fiz assim. Mas depois que termina a função não consigo habilitar esse elemento de novo para clicar.
Esse elemento roda outra função, mais abaixo.

`$("div#back-exit > .back").off('click');`

```
$("div#back-exit > .back").on('click', function(e){
    media.stop("chime-01");
    media.stop("tada"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu costumo usar outra abordagem para este problema. Em vêz de juntar ambos os eventos ao event listener do jQuery uso

```
var clickDeviceEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
```

e depois:

```
$('#boxes > .box').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
```

Se não fôr o caso de ser útil refazeres o código com essa lógica sugiro usares uma `flag`. Sabendo que o `touchstart` dispara primeiro que o `click` basta colocares algo como

```
var clickAtivo = true;
$('#boxes > .box').on("touchstart", function(){
    clickAtivo = false;
    var cor = $(this.data('cor');
    // resto do código
```

e na outra função:

```
}).on("touchstart click", function(e){
    if (!clickAtivo) return;
    // etc...
```

e depois quando a função chegar ao fim (parece-me ser na linha `media.play(audio);`) podes colocar uma linha nova

```
clickAtivo = true;
```

que vai deixar de bloquear o `click`.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode desabilitar eventos de mouse sobre os elementos **alterando o atributo `pointer-events` do estilo CSS do elemento**.

Em seu caso específico, no início de seu método você deve executar o código abaixo para desabilitar os clicks na div:

```
// Desabilita todos os eventos de mouse/click na div.
$("div#back-exit > .back").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

Ao final de seu método, para reativar os eventos de click na div, você executa o código a seguir:

```
// Habilita novamente os eventos de click/mouse na div.
$("#button_id").css("pointer-events", "auto");
```

*Resposta adaptada de https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095924/1639385*

Comment: Mas essa propriedade funciona bem em todos os browsers ?

Comment: Se o browser for muito antigo ou se for IE antes da versão 11 é necessário fazer ajustes. No seu caso específico, quais browsers e versões você quer que seu jogo suporte?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usas o evento `setAttribute` dessa forma:

```js
function desabilitarFunção(id){
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('onclick', 'desabilitado()');
}

function habilitarFunção(id){
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('onclick', 'habilitado()');
}

function desabilitado(){
  alert("Est\u00e1 fun\u00e7\u00e3o est\u00e1 desabilitada!!");
}

function habilitado(){
  alert("fun\u00e7\u00e3o est\u00e1 habilitada!!");
  //sua função habilitada
}
```

```css
.botao{
  width: 90px;
  height: 26px;

  border: 3px rgb(89,89,89) double;

  background: rgb(239, 155, 155);

  color: rgb(25,25,25);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-align: center;

  line-height: 1.3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="botao" onclick="habilitado();">click-me</div>

<br/><br/>

<input type="button" onclick="desabilitarFunção('div1')" value="Desabilitar Função da DIV">
<input type="button" onclick="habilitarFunção('div1')" value="Habilitar Função da DIV">
```

Se você simplesmente quiser que não execute nada é só setar o atributo como: `document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('onclick', '');`

---

Com `JQuery`:

```js
function desabilitarFunção(id){
  $("#"+id).removeAttr('onclick', 'habilitado()');
  $("#"+id).attr('onclick', 'desabilitado()');
}

function habilitarFunção(id){
  $("#"+id).removeAttr('onclick', 'desabilitado()');
  $("#"+id).attr('onclick', 'habilitado()');
}

function desabilitado(){
  alert("Est\u00e1 fun\u00e7\u00e3o est\u00e1 desabilitada!!");
}

function habilitado(){
  alert("fun\u00e7\u00e3o est\u00e1 habilitada!!");
  //sua função habilitada
}
```

```css
.botao{
      width: 90px;
      height: 26px;

      border: 3px rgb(89,89,89) double;

      background: rgb(239, 155, 155);

      color: rgb(25,25,25);
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-style: inherit;
      text-decoration: inherit;
      text-align: center;

      line-height: 1.3em;
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" class="botao" onclick="habilitado();">click-me</div>

<br/><br/>

<input type="button" onclick="desabilitarFunção('div1')" value="Desabilitar Função da DIV">
<input type="button" onclick="habilitarFunção('div1')" value="Habilitar Função da DIV">
```

Comment: Estou utilizando jQuery.

Comment: Funciona do mesmo jeito que `JQuery`, mas eu recomendo a utilização do `JavaScript` puro

Comment: Por que você recomenda ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Por que VOCÊ recomenda ?

Comment: Muitas vezes nos empolgamos por facilidades que um plugin ou uma plataforma representa para nós programadores, então adotamo-as como fonte de uso para absolutamente TUDO, isso ocorre muito com o JQuery, pelo menos eu vejo isso, tanto no ambiente de trabalho quanto a nível de conhecimento... Veja bem, NÃO DESAPROVO, mas acho que pra algumas funções básicas, como setar atributo, remover atributo, e outras coisas que com JS puro podemos fazer facilmente... NESSE PONTO eu adoto uma abordagem mais cética quanto aos benefícios do uso dessa ou de outras bibliotecas.

Comment: Utilizar essa ferramenta poderosa somente por 1 ou 2 recursos que podem ser feitos com JS puro, seria algo como possuir uma Ferrari, mas só usar o câmbio da mesma.